# Calling an extension from another extension: save full page as HTML complete web page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a Firefox's button that performs several actions I use to do frequently in a sequence. One of the actions is to save the web page as HTML, but implementing this action is creating difficulties for me. This functionality is already implemented in Firefox: you can access it through "File" -> "Save Page As" -> "Web page, complete". However, I did not find the way to call that functionality from the code of my own button. Maybe the answer is in https://searchfox.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/content/contentAreaUtils.js, but I cannot see it.

Currently, I am able to download the page as simple .html using browser.downloads.download(...). However, this does not keep images or any other resource. It seems quite complex to programmatically deal with all those elements "by hand".

An alternative I thought of was using an extra extension (like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/single-file/ / https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile or https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/singlefilez/) and calling the corresponding function from the code of my button, but I don't know how to do that either.

Any suggestion would be very welcome. I have the feeling that this should not be difficult to solve, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

---

Author of SingleFile/SingleFileZ here, you can use [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) from your extension to communicate with SingleFile/SingleFileZ. See here for more info about the accepted messages: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile/issues/1186#issuecomment-1646838753. It's also documented in the help page of the extension.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!! Any solution not requiring an extension? "Save page as" -> "Web page, complete" works very well for me (and keeps all the files separate rather than in a single file), but I want to include as part of what is executed when clicking a button.

Comment: This is not the same question. You should create a new question on SO.